# TFS API DownloadFile( ) functions cause exception when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs-sdk

Whenever I call Item.DownloadFile(string localFileName) or VersionControlServer.DownloadFile(string serverPath, string localFileName) I get a FileNotFoundException whenever I try to debug in Visual Studio: Could not find file 'C:[Project Path]\bin\Debug\[ProjectName].vshost.exe.config'.

When I build the application and run it outside of visual studio there is no problem calling these functions. It works perfectly fine. Anyone know what could be causing it?

Before you ask, no, that file does not exist. I'm not doing anything with a config file, I don't need or want it to exist. I don't understand why it is even trying to access that file when I debug. When I run the application outside of visual studio that .config file still does not exist but I get no exception because it's not trying to access that file.

Also, it is not a vshost problem either. When I uncheck "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" I get the same exception except when debugging but the file name changes from "[ProjectName].vshost.exe.config" to "[ProjectName].config"

Currently, when I want to debug this project I have to put a MessageBox.Show( ) function right after every call to DownloadFile( ) and run my application outside of visual studio. When that MessageBox is displayed then I can use attach to process and put a break point on the next line after that MessageBox, click OK on the messagebox and then it will catch the break point. But when I'm downloading files in a loop and want to debug the loop it's extremely annoying and time consuming to attach to process after DownloadFile is called, stop debugging before the next DownloadFile is called, attach to process again after DownloadFile is called, and keep repeating that all day long.

Comment: Do you have UAC activated on your Windows ? Does Visual Studio runs as administrator?

Comment: Not sure what UAC means, but yes it does run as administrator.

Comment: User Access Control, the feature introduced in Vista to run the programs in restricted privileges and with the possibility to elevate when the program required more rights.
Even if you're logged with an admin account, if UAC is activated you'll be restricted on some operations. To start Visual Studio, right click on the icon then choose "run as administrator"

Comment: The problem was that Visual Studio's Debug exceptions were set to break when an exception is *thrown* instead of when an exception is *unhandled*. So DownloadFile( ) is throwing an exception, but it is handling it so you can't tell it's getting thrown. Unfortunately my Visual Studio was setup to "break" when an exception is thrown, even if it is handled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but looks like it has something to do with the current path and the Workspace where you download the file to.

If you don't explicitly specify the workspace, the TFS API will try to determine it from the current path of your application by looking if that path is declared in a Workspace as a Mapping.

If I remember correctly, you can download an item from a Workspace object (or specify the Workspace in the operation), try to modify your code to do that and see if it's better.

You can also try to change the current path of your debugging session to something "inside a Workspace"

Comment: DownloadFile is not the same as a Get. Get requires a workspace to download to. The DownloadFile function is ignorant to workspaces and you explicitly pass it the path to download the file to.